# Setting a button in a Title Bar of an Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, button, titlebar

I know that it is possible to add a Back Button to a Title Bar in an Android app, by setting:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        ...
        android:parentActivityName=".SomeActivity"
        ... />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml.

Is it also possible to add an arbitrary button with some functionality in the Title Bar?

If YES, what is the way to do it?

Comment: If you use the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar) class as your action bar, you can add anything you want to it between the title and the action menu, because it's a ViewGroup. Instructions here: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Comment: @Tenfour04. I am looking into your tip and try to follow the document you mention. I can remove the original bar, but then I have problems with android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. If I use it as in the doc I get: error: unexpected element <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> found in <manifest><application><activity>.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know what would cause that. I’ve never had a problem with it.

Comment: @Tenfour04. Thanks to your first comment I got to realize that Toolbar was a whole subject of itself that I did not really know about. I spent some time checking out some tutorials and I now have a button working as I wanted.